# Checkbox checked event in gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, checkbox

I have gridview with two bound fields and a template on item template i have a checkbox now i want to check the checked checkbox and want to retrieve the checkbox text i had find the control in row databound but the problem is as soon as i debug the code doest not proceed and it gets looped under this event :

```
protected void ProdView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox ch1 = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
        if (ch1.Checked == true)
        {
            Session["rechargeid"] = ch1.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

and does not proceed can somebody suggest me a possible way to do so....?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (GridViewRow rw in gv_discpoint.Rows)
{
    CheckBox chkfill = (CheckBox)rw.FindControl("txtchk");
    TextBox txtaction = (TextBox)rw.FindControl("txtAction");
    TextBox txttarget = (TextBox)rw.FindControl("txttarget");
    if (chkfill.Checked == true)
    { // do something }
    else if (chkfill.Checked == false)
    { // do something }
}
```

Comment: it is not working either every time the page loads it goes into into a infinite loop well it has to be because every time the page loads  the grid_rowdatabound call but this dosent slove my problem ....please suggest me a possible way ...

Comment: don't use page load event using button click or any other event

Answer (score 0):

FYI `RowDataBound` event works when data is bound to the grid view. For example, if you are binding a data table to the grid view and the data table has 5 rows, `RowDataBound` fires 5 times (sometimes more).

As from under standing your question, what you need is some postback method (by a button click) that gets all the checked checkbox's texts. If you are keeping a button and the click of it should fetch you your need the code would be the following

```
 protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

       for(int i=0; i<gridView.Rows.Count; i++)
       {
           CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gridView.Rows[i].FindControl("CheckBox1");
           if (cb.Checked == true)
           {

               // use cb.Text to retrieve the checkbox text
           }

       }
 }
```